# How to make a page template for displaying custom type posts

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I just started WP, and made a table with many rows arrived at WP house. But don't know how to show. basic content well shown but custom fields. learnt that a page have to be created to deal them in order to retrieve custom typed posts.

the following is from my content-movie.php under twentyfourteenchild:

/* translators: %s: Name of current post */

the_content();

// handling movie stuff starts

$p_id = $post->ID;

$ar_fields = array( 'studio','director','starring','grade');

.

.

foreach $ar_fields as $field

$some_field = get_post_custom_values($field,  $p_id);

do some thing dealing $some_field...

end for

===================

In order to make a regular page to populate movie-typed custom posts, do I have to put such codes in archive-movie, page-movie single-movie etc ?

I guess, somewhere it can be dealt instead of putting same scripts in many files.

I really want someone to help me go right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

firstly create a custom page template by doing the following:

Copy the regular page.php and rename it to page-movies.php.

In the page header add the following php code:

```
/**
 * Template Name: Movie Page
 */
```

Now the page template should be available in the backend, select the Movie Page as your page template.

Now replace the regular page query with your query, here is an example below:

```
 <?php $args = array( 'numberposts' => 7, 'order'=> 'ASC', 'post_type' => 'movies');    
                $postslist = get_posts( $args );
                foreach ($postslist as $post) :  setup_postdata($post);  ?>
            <div class="item">
              <div class="item-content">
                <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
                <div class="thumbnails"> <a class="ajax" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                  <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'projects-thumbnail' ); ?>
                  </a>
                  <div class="copy">
                    <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?> ">
                      <?php the_title(); ?>
                      </a></h3>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
              </div>
            </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
```

This should do the trick...

Comment: 5 mis limittion for commenting... so newbie to this stack. Now, time to kill paging stuff in Page. codex reads setup_postdata does not assign global $post as i understand. showing not page nav stuff by above code means twentyfourteen theme seems still looking at main query, I quess. Ok, this is different ballpark than this post. Anyway, thank you so much.

Comment: Glad to hear it is working, please mark the above as the accepted answer. Start a new thread for your issue and send me the link. I will look at it to you.

Comment: Hi just a tip, check out http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/ it really made custom fields a breeze!

Comment: I cannot find a word to say to your timely help. as I guessed, no need to put dirty codes in everywhere. awesome. Got already ACF housed in, another  jewel.

Comment: twentyfifteen and fourteen, even thirteen they work differently, I learned. Weird. especially pagination in a regular page displaying posts. i need a bit more hassel for this issue before openning new thread, then i will let you know.

Comment: Ok just let me know, there is a way to do this which will be compatible across all  themes!

Comment: By the way, is there other action in here except just clicking Accept marking ? like reword point ? You definitely are the one rewarded if any. please let me know how to. I am totally new to stack. up until, i can not find loggout button in this page.